# How to properly convert onclick to onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, onclick, onsubmit

I have a form which is used to upload files to our google drive, and I needed to create validation for some of the fields.  And after much googling I figured out that you needed to use `onsubmit` instead of `onclick` to get validation to work.

However, when I went to convert things from onclick to onsubmit, while the validation began to work, the file upload function broke and nothing happened when someone hit the submit ("Upload File") button.

The original code was as follows:

```
<form id="myForm"  >
<center>Please deposit your file using the submission form below.</center>
<br>
<br>
   <font size="3" color="red">*</font>Your Name: <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name.." required />
   <font size="3" color="red">*</font>Your Email: <small><b>(to contact in case of questions, and send your file deposit receipt)</b></small> <input type="email" name="userMail" placeholder="Your email.." required />
   <br>
   <font size="3" color="red">*</font>File Recipient Name: <input type="text" name="recName" placeholder="Your recipient's name.." required />
   <font size="3" color="red">*</font>File Recipient Email: <small><b>(whom to notify of your deposit)</b></small> <input type="email" name="recEmail" placeholder="Your recipient's email.." required />
   <br>
   School: <small><b>(if your file pertains to a specific school)</b></small> <input type="text" name="aSchool" placeholder="Pertaining school.." /> 
   School Year: <small><b>(if your file pertains to a specific school year)</b></small> <input type="text" name="aSchoolYear" placeholder="Pertaining school year.." />
   <br>
   Note(s): <small><b>(any special note about the file)</b></small> <br> <textarea name="sNote" rows="3" cols="40" > </textarea>
   <br>
   <br>
    <input type="file" name="myFile" required />
    <br>

      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;" />
</form>
```

And I converted the `onclick` to `onsubmit` like so:

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onsubmit="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this);
                    return false;" />
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong or if there is a different way to do validation and retain `onclick`?

Answer (score 0):

when you change to onsubmit, `this` becomes the form itself, not the submit button.

The better way to do it (in my opinion) is implement the event in JQuery syntax, something like

```
$(document).on('submit', "#myForm", function(e) {
    var formObj = $(e.currentTarget);
    formObj.find("input[type='submit']").val("Uploading..");
    ....
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner at this and have not worked with jQuery .. is there a way to do it in the existing syntax?

I listened to what you said about `this` becoming the form, and went ahead and tried to change my code to the following:


`<input type="submit" name=mySubmit value="Upload File" 
           onclick="mySubmit.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(mySubmit.parentNode);
                    return false;" />`


But it still did not work and hung up after pressing "Upload File".

Thoughts?

Comment: If you have FireBug installed in Firefox, can you take a look at Console tab and click Upload File again, see if there is any error

Comment: After many attempts at JavaScript, you've pushed me to learn jQuery.  And after some time, I was able to figure out how things went, and then I got the code you recommended going! .. but I'm finding it hard to finish your function with respect to duplicating all the tasks that the `onclick` used to do.  Such as `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);` and `return false;` .. though from my research, the `return false;` looks to be done the same way, and I tried `.uploadFiles($(this).closest('tr')[0])` for the node, but its wrong?